# Auto Increment based on grouping

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a auto increment column that should be based on group. That column should get incremented based on the last largest column within that group. Following set of queries gives me two different results. Can anyone please advise what might be the reason?

```
 1. CREATE TABLE animals (
grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id,grp)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

 INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
('bird','ostrich');

select * from  animals; 

 Result:

     grp     id  name    

    | mammal |  1 | dog     |
    | mammal |  2 | cat     |
    | bird   |  3 | penguin |
    | fish   |  4 | lax     |
    | mammal |  5 | whale   |
    | bird   |  6 | ostrich |
    +--------+----+---------+



2. CREATE TABLE animals (
      grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)

    ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

    INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
    ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
    ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
    ('bird','ostrich');  

    select * from  animals; 

    Result:
    +--------+----+---------+
    | grp    | id | name    |
    +--------+----+---------+
    | mammal |  1 | dog     |
    | mammal |  2 | cat     |
    | bird   |  1 | penguin |
    | fish   |  1 | lax     |
    | mammal |  3 | whale   |
    | bird   |  2 | ostrich |
    +--------+----+---------+
```

The only change between two sets of queries is the order of columns mentioned in the PRIMARY_KEY() of CREATE TABLE Query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have the answer in your question: "the order of columns mentioned in the PRIMARY_KEY()"

Comment: Anyway, don't use MyISAM. Use InnoDB, and don't worry about the id not incrementing per group. That's a display problem, not a data storage problem.

Comment: Also read "For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a **secondary** column in a multiple-column index." from where you have copied your example.

Comment: I have copied this example from https://dev.mysql.com/. And Yes i have gone through this statement "For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index". But i am not able to get the essence of the sentence. Can you please explain it if possible?

Comment: "secondary" means: it's not the first. The "group" for the sequence is defined by the PK columns which come before the AI column. If the PK is (id, grp) then the `id` is the **first** column, and thus not **secondary**.